# reading fortran exponential notation in cpp

Tags: c++, c, fortran, scanf

I have an output from fortran program. It looks like:

```
  -0.218992624383943335E+001   0.141709629412732530E+001   0.798866756359534413E+000
  -0.333162729303917438E+001   0.544763361230827758E+001   0.352566739381167604E+001
  -0.633341755881933866E+000  -0.254058697110871812E+001  -0.712520767968274127E+000
```

What is the easiest way to get these numbers read into C or C++ code (sscanf)?

Answer (score 0):

Use C++ streams:

```
ifstream file("name");

double number;
file >> number;
```